# How to configure multiple GPU in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, gpu-driver

First time posting here - so if I am not completely compliant of the rules here, I apologize in advance.

I am relatively new with Linux, and I recently installed ubuntu 16.04, replacing my windows 10 in a custom build desktop. I am asking how does one configure multi-GPUs in Ubuntu?

There are the two cards that I have in the case: GTX 1080 and GTX 760 OEM. I have followed a tutorial and installed driver(`nvidia-375`) successfully. I unplugged GTX 760 OEM as of now just in case of any unexpected complications, thus, GTX 1080 should be the only GPU in the system.

The question is: In "Additional Drivers" ([Additional Driver Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYL9u.png)), it shows that I am using GTX 760 OEM. I am wondering why this is the case, since according to Nvidia X server Settings ([Nvidia X Server Settings Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGa3J.png)), I am using GTX 1080.

Furthermore, when I try plugging both GPUs in, one of the GPU would be running with "*Using X.Org X Server - Noueveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau(open source)*". If I switch both GPU with Nvidia driver, the screen will just turn black and show a line as if I turned off `lightdm`. Is it supposed to be this way?